# three.js drag and drop tracking

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to track objects in dragging and dropping to have info about from where the object is dragged and to where it is dropped, how can I make that possible?

The actual cause is that I'am developing a game where I should track the source and destination points, I should verify success only if the any shape is taken and placed from and to a particular place only.

raycaster gives a intersection array but that is to intersection from cursor, not any other object.

This page from script tutorials can be taken for example : https://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/467/index.html

Comment: I built this logic sometime back on AI Turing test. You can simply achieve this by reading the specific material and only match making that material to increase the complexity make the material selection random

Comment: Not sure if i understand it correctly... After releasing the object you can get its position and then you know where it is. If you want to know if it's on or inside a certain object you try google for 'collision detection threejs'. Maybe that helps. Good luck.